# Spring bean instantiation ordering

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, applicationcontext

I have run into an issue where Bean instantiation sequencing matters. Currently Bean3 from below is running a DB based cache put operation, and Bean 1 queries against the newly created cache using Proxy Bean2. Priority is for Bean3 and Bean 2 to be completely instantiated before Bean1 gets instantiated, i.e. when Spring container comes up. These beans are in seperate JARS, and Bean2 reference into Bean1 is not using Autowired. Instead a service locator is giving it a reference. We are using Spring 2.5.2 and not using XML for instantiation of beans. Any help appreciated!

- JAR1 (Spring project)

  ```
  @Service ("bean3")   
   public class Bean3 implements ApplicationListener  { 
      public void onApplicationEvent() {  
        //load data from DB and populate cache                    
      }
       public void getCache(){
       //get data from cache
      }
  ```

  }

  ```
  @Service ("bean2")
  public class Bean2 { 
  @Autowired 
  private Bean3 bean3;
     private void methodA(){
       bean3.getCache();
     }
  }
  ```
- JAR2 (Non-Spring project)

  ```
  public class Bean1{  
  Bean2 bean2 = SpringServiceLocator.getBean("bean2")
    public void methodB(){
      bean2.methodA();
     } 
  }
  ```

Comment: Are you using constructor based autowiring?

Comment: We have enabled the auto-discovery mode in JAR1 for autowiring.

Comment: Would it be feasible to make Bean1 dependent on Bean2 (or create a chain of dependencies?) When is the method from Bean1 called?

Comment: The Bean 2 reference into Bean 1 is being given by a Spring Service locator utility (home grown),since Bean1 is in a non-spring project. I have edited my question to better structure my issue

Comment: @AKSM What is not working as expected? You mentioned a home grown Spring Service locator utility. If Bean1 is a non-spring project then the instantiation order is probably completely in the hands of that utility. So I think I am missing an important peace of information about your scenario.

Comment: The problem in this scenario was Bean3's onApplicationEvent(), which is loading data into cache after the complete container initialization. The problem had nothing to do with bean initialization ordering. We are currently trying to override the init-method on Bean3, and load the data into cache during initialization. This way, requests from Bean1/Bean2 will not die

Comment: I assume using @PostConstruct on your init method solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to perform some logic on application startup (context init).

If this is the case, I would suggest that you use BeanPostProcessor, to perform any special operations at application startup.

```
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        .. **perform special things**
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        ..**perform special things**
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Do not forget to tell Spring about your post processor

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package" />
<bean class="some.package.MyBeanPostProcessor"
```

For more info read here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s07.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your homegrew Spring Service locator need a signal like below

```
        Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition springready = l.newCondition();

        l.lock();
        try {
          while (READY_FLAG)
              springready.await();

            ...

        } finally {
          l.unlock();
        }
```

in addition

you can listen ContextRefreshedEvent to change READY_FLAG and signal 'springready'

Comment: i cant shared the code we are using for some reasons, but it just like that